# CentOS 7 graphical UI sluggish and freezing

Tags: centos, desktop-environment

I would like to get a desktop system as light as possible. I downloaded CentOS but I got something that freeze so much that login takes 1 minutes, registering takes 5 minutes, opening Menu takes 3 minutes.

Is it possible to get a GUI which is able to work on two screen without a advanced graphical card?

I would like to use only the normal DVD-ROM, or since I cannot connect to the Internet, something which is delivered in a DVD-ROM.

Is it even possible?

I have 700Go HD, 4 Go Memory, A simple graphical cart.

Comment: It might help if you list your hardware limitations and what sort of use you want to make of the system. Also, I'd try to re-word your Q so the possible answer is less likely to be opinion based.

Comment: What do you mean with "two screen"? You have a multi-monitor setup and you think this could have something to do with your problem?

Comment: Also you might try switching to text-only shells using a vertial console, which you can normally access using e.g. ctrl+alt+F6, use then ctrl+alt+F7 to go back to your graphical UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some comments along with (what I hope will be) a useful answer.

### Considerations

#### Machine specs

**High End**: Go for the latest distros with a light desktop environment (shown further down)

**Medium**: Look for some older distros, maybe 1 or 2 years old that still got support.

**Low End**: Go for some barebones distros with light desktop environments

### What you need

It would be really useful to know what are you looking for. Maybe a linux sandbox? A development machine? A test machine?

### Your Options

#### Very Light Distros

**Lubuntu**: Needless to say, based on Ubuntu, using LXDE for desktop environment, you can find it at http://lubuntu.net/

**Absolute Linux**: Based on Slackware, its main focus is to revive older machines. Perfect for low end (32 bits only). Hosted at http://www.absolutelinux.org/

#### Other Distros

The following list must be taken with a grain of salt. And run with a lightweight desktop environment like XFCE or LXDE.

Check their sites for further information: [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) | [LXDE](http://lxde.org/)

As for the distros, these are some of the most popular without any particular order.

- **[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/):** I've heard people say "It's Debian done in the right way"
- **[CentOS](https://www.centos.org/):** RPM based, it's like the free cousin of Red Hat
- **[Fedora](https://getfedora.org/):** Based on Red Hat too, is widely popular among RPM enthusiasts
- **[OpenSuse](https://www.opensuse.org/):** Another one using RPM repos, it's called one of the most "Windows-like" linux distros ever.

I hope this information guides you to find the right distro + the right desktop environment for you.